# How to get the real address in a stack trace of android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a problem when using addr2line in android while my application got a SIGSEGV signal and crashed.

here is the stacktrace:

```
    08-22 12:35:31.883: I/DEBUG(2332): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-22 12:35:31.883: I/DEBUG(2332): Build fingerprint: 'generic/bcm7241_guangxi/bcm7241:4.0.1/ICS_MR0/eng.wuzhigang.20130409.170739:eng/test-keys'
08-22 12:35:31.884: I/DEBUG(2332): pid: 1127, tid: 1228  >>> com.my.alc <<<
08-22 12:35:31.884: I/DEBUG(2332): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 17c33007
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  zr 00000000  at 00000000  v0 283d6680  v1 283d6524
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  a0 17c33007  a1 f4404300  a2 f4404300  a3 17c33007
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  t0 17c33007  t1 00000000  t2 00000000  t3 00000000
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  t4 2e6bb000  t5 2e6cb000  t6 000018ff  t7 0000000f
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  s0 000000dc  s1 5c2eba88  s2 0000000f  s3 fffff4d4
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  s4 2e7c7408  s5 0105d0e8  s6 00000100  s7 00000000
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  t8 5c030cd0  t9 779c3820  k0 00000002  k1 00000000
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  gp 2e6c4000  sp 2e7c73a0  s8 2e6c7fa0  ra 5c04ef69
08-22 12:35:31.885: I/DEBUG(2332):  hi 00000408  lo bd84cc00 bva 17c33007 epc 282112a8
08-22 12:35:31.920: E/Cocos2dxBitmap(1127): error to create ttf type face: /system/fonts/FZLTXH_GBK.ttf
08-22 12:35:31.955: E/Cocos2dxBitmap(1127): error to create ttf type face: /system/fonts/FZLTXH_GBK.ttf
08-22 12:35:32.015: D/dalvikvm(1127): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1665K, 25% free 18494K/24455K, paused 2ms+15ms
08-22 12:35:32.566: I/DEBUG(2332):          #00  pc 282112a8 sp 2e7c73a0   
08-22 12:35:32.566: I/DEBUG(2332):          #01  pc 5c04ef69 sp 2e7c73a8  /data/data/com.my.alc/lib/libmyapp.so
08-22 12:35:32.573: I/DEBUG(2332):          #01  ra 5c04ef69  /data/data/com.my.alc/lib/libmyapp.so
08-22 12:35:32.574: I/DEBUG(2332): code around pc:
08-22 12:35:32.576: I/DEBUG(2332): 28211288 033fc824 0009ffc0 001fff82 033fc825  $.?.........%.?.
08-22 12:35:32.576: I/DEBUG(2332): 28211298 8fbf0000 27bd0008 01003825 02407825  .......'%8..%x@.
08-22 12:35:32.576: I/DEBUG(2332): 282112a8 a0f00000 01e09025 24010001 00e14021  ....%......$!@..
08-22 12:35:32.576: I/DEBUG(2332): 282112b8 0101482b 00e15026 01075826 01405027  +H..&P..&X..'P@.
08-22 12:35:32.576: I/DEBUG(2332): 282112c8 014b5024 000a57c2 27bdfff8 afbf0000  $PK..W.....'....
08-22 12:35:32.577: I/DEBUG(2332): code around ra:
08-22 12:35:32.577: I/DEBUG(2332): 5c04ef48 e7ec60eb f7e11c38 e7e8fe09 1e04b570  .`..8.......p...
08-22 12:35:32.577: I/DEBUG(2332): 5c04ef58 6820d012 d0132800 008968a1 feaef7e1  .. h.(...h......
08-22 12:35:32.578: I/DEBUG(2332): 5c04ef68 07ab6925 1c20d509 f7e12114 07ebfea7  %i.... ..!......
08-22 12:35:32.578: I/DEBUG(2332): 5c04ef78 1c20d502 fdf2f7e1 6820bd70 fdeef7e1  .. .....p. h....
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): 5c04ef88 e7f06925 480bb500 4478b083 2b006903  %i.....H..xD.i.+
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): memory map around addr 17c33007:
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): 10001000-10100000 
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): (no map for address)
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): 27fae000-2820e000 
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332): stack:
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332):     2e7c7360  5c04617b  /data/data/com.my.alc/lib/libmyapp.so
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332):     2e7c7364  5c0456a3  /data/data/com.my.alc/lib/libmyapp.so
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332):     2e7c7368  00000000  
08-22 12:35:32.579: I/DEBUG(2332):     2e7c736c  5c04617b  /data/data/com.my.alc/lib/libmyapp.so
08-22 12:35:32.580: I/DEBUG(2332):     2e7c7370  00009004
```

1) i know how to use addr2line to get the real inmy libmyapp.so, but it's easy when the address is like `0x00__, 0x01__, 0x02`..

2) the problem is that the `pc 5c04ef69 sp 2e7c73a8` is a relative address in memory,  Is there a way **to convert 5c04ef69  to 0x00_____?**

3) from google there is a similar question 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/TAzIvZiR_yk
, but in my dumptrace i can't find the address to subtrace like  `#00  pc 003c329a`, my device is Android 4.0.2, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be a problem unique to MIPS CPUs. You need to know the start address of the library. With ASLR you may not be able to just strip off the high 12 bits or so.

Comment: Hi fadden, yes it's a BCM MIPS cpu,   is there any way to ge the start address of the library?